# Object tracking with Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

As far as I know, the main features of Project Tango SDK are:

- motion tracking
- area learning
- depth perception

But what about object recognition & tracking?

I didn't see anything about that in the SDK, though I assume that Tango hardware would be really good at it (compared with traditional smartphones). Why?

**Update 2017/06/05**

A [marker detection API](https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes#marker_detection_api) has been introduced in the Hopak release

Answer (score 3):

There are already good libraries for object tracking in 2D images and the additional features of project tango would likely add only marginal improvement in performance(of existing functions) for major overhauls of the library to support a small set of evolving hardware.

How do you think project tango could improve on existing object recognition & tracking?

With a 3d model of the object to be tracked, and knowledge of the motion and pose of the camera, one could predict what the next image of the tracked object 'should' look like.  If the next image is different than predicted, it could be assumed that the tracked object has moved from its prior position.  And the actual new 3D image could indicate the tracked object's vectors.  That certainly has uses in navigating a live environment.

But that sounds like the sort of solution a self driving car might use.  And that would be a valuable piece of tech worth keeping away from competitors despite its value to the community.

This is all just speculation.  I have no first hand knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm really not an expert in image processing so that was just an open question: I understand that Tango is good & fast at visual features extraction, so I assumed that it could be useful for object tracking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're expecting for an "open question", but I can tell you one common way that people exploit Tango's capabilities to aid object recognition & tracking.  Tango's point cloud, image callbacks, and pose data can be used as input for a library like PCL (http://pointclouds.org/).

Simply browsing the documentation & tutorials will give you a good idea of what's possible and how it can be achieved.

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/

Beyond that, you might browse the pcl-users mail archives:

http://www.pcl-users.org/